Why the Apps I download from the internet has missing icons?
I am on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and everytime i download something from internet (Like tar.gz files) and then launch them, they don't have app icons and specific names. Can someone really help me?! I don't feel good when there isn't icons.

This is hardly answerable, especially if you want a general answer. We are not the authors of that software. You'd better ask more specific. Give us an example, provide download link and then someone will probably be able to answer something useful.

.tar.gz USUALLY are not the programs themselves but the source code to thus compile and build and install those applications.  That's usually not what you're after if your only goal is to install the software on your system.  However, as written, this is too unclear
